# Prototype UI - carousel with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, prototypejs, carousel

Does anyone know if it's possible to create a carousel of images in prototype and then drag+drop those images from the carousel onto a droppable div?

I've tried the same thing using jQuery UI's draggable/droppable plugins with jCarousel without luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the trick to doing this is to carefully manage containment of the carousel. My experience of Drag and Drop with Prototype/Scriptaculous has been that if the source is contained within an element with overflow set to hidden or scroll then you can't drag out of it. Carousels are often contained in div's with the overflow set to hidden so if the animations to move from one image to another are not perfectly in sync the element size doesn't pulse.

One option would be to have your carousel use equally sized images which are absolutely positioned, to the same co-ordinates, and simply fade from one to the next, then the containment can be simple (or have none at all), then the scripty drag/drop should work ok.